# Converting a list of lists to a dictionary and calling values using a for loop

Tags: python

I have a list of single-element lists:

```
geos = [["'latitude': 12.1234, 'longitude': -12.1234, 'accuracy': 100"],
        ["'latitude': 12.1233, 'longitude': -12.1233, 'accuracy': 100"],
        ["'latitude': 12.1222, 'longitude': -12.1111, 'accuracy': 100"],
        ["'latitude': 12.1111, 'longitude': -12.1222, 'accuracy': 100"]]
```

I've acquired the data in this format from elsewhere. What I'd like to achieve from here is converting this list of lists into a dictionary so that I can pass in the correct parameters relevant to my `for` loop. This is where I'm at so far:

```
geos_dict = {geo[0]:None for geo in geos}

for i, geos_dict in enumerate(geos_dict):
     options = ChromeOptions()
     options.add_argument("--headless")
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('/Library/path/chromedriver'))
     driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Browser.grantPermissions", {"origin": 
               "https://www.google.com","permissions": ["geolocation"]})
     #This is the line where the error is occurring   
     driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", 
            {"latitude": geo["latitude"], "longitude": 
            geo["longitude"], "accuracy": geo["accuracy"]})
     driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I'm returning an error: **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Obviously, I'm not doing this right. But I don't know enough about converting lists to dictionaries and calling values from the key:value pair.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how do I convert the list to a dictionary and pass the correct parameters to 'latitude', 'longitude', and 'accuracy'

Comment: We don't really need the whole first part of this for a complete [mre] if all you're looking to do is convert the intermediate result (the list of lists) to a list of dictionarties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element in your list is a single-element list, and that single element is a string. That string represents a dictionary, minus the opening and closing curly braces. [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) provides a safe way to parse literal data structures like this.

Also: you say you want to convert `geos` into a dictionary, and your code does so, but what you must actually want is a list *of* dictionaries to then loop over.

```
from ast import literal_eval
from pprint import pprint

geos = [["'latitude': 12.1234, 'longitude': -12.1234, 'accuracy': 100"],
        ["'latitude': 12.1233, 'longitude': -12.1233, 'accuracy': 100"],
        ["'latitude': 12.1222, 'longitude': -12.1111, 'accuracy': 100"],
        ["'latitude': 12.1111, 'longitude': -12.1222, 'accuracy': 100"]]

geos = [literal_eval(f'{{{geo[0]}}}') for geo in geos]

pprint(geos, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output (using [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) to more easily see the nested structure):

```
[{'latitude': 12.1234, 'longitude': -12.1234, 'accuracy': 100},
 {'latitude': 12.1233, 'longitude': -12.1233, 'accuracy': 100},
 {'latitude': 12.1222, 'longitude': -12.1111, 'accuracy': 100},
 {'latitude': 12.1111, 'longitude': -12.1222, 'accuracy': 100}]
```

That's a formatted string literal or ["f-string"](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), by the way. You can include variables or other expressions inside such a string with `{}`, and you can escape, that is, include a literal `{`, with `{{`. So all that f-string does is put `{}` around each string to make it a valid representation of a dictionary.

Comment: If you want to make the output a dictionary, simply add an index in a dictionary comprehension:
d = {i: literal_eval(f'{{{g[0]}}}') for i, g in enumerate(geos)}
And the output from that is:
{0: {'latitude': 12.1234, 'longitude': -12.1234, 'accuracy': 100},
 1: {'latitude': 12.1233, 'longitude': -12.1233, 'accuracy': 100},
 2: {'latitude': 12.1222, 'longitude': -12.1111, 'accuracy': 100},
 3: {'latitude': 12.1111, 'longitude': -12.1222, 'accuracy': 100}}

Comment: @CarlosMelus That's nearly impossible to read. Please at least put back ticks around code in comments to code-format it, or better yet post your own answer where you can use newlines and syntax highlighting. That said, from the code shown trying to *use* the result, I don't think a dictionary makes any sense for the asker's purpose.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I agree it does not look nice. I didn't want to simply leverage your answer and wanted to give you credit for it (`literal_eval` is awesome in this scenario).
Also, the OP is asking for a dictionary as the output, whether we think it makes sense or not. That is why I proposed that solution, and making the indices match the original list just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit slow but you want something like this

```py
import re
parser = re.compile("'latitude': (.*), 'longitude': (.*), 'accuracy': (.*)")

for geo in geos:
   match = parser.match(geo[0])
   # in match object will be 3 groups
   lat, long, acc = match.groups()
   geo_dict = {'latitude': lat, 'longitude': long, 'accuracy' : acc}

   ... #
   driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", geo_dict)
```

Comment: regex can ofcourse be improved